# Sending values from Child to Parent with C#/Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, polymorphism

I am sending data from a child to a parent and then calculating a walk path. When I send the data, it runs through the FindPath function and returns a list of values.
But, when the Update runs, WalkTo has been set to 0 again. Why is the new data not being kept?

I have verified that WalkTo is not being reset to 0 anywhere between the two function.

```
public class ParentClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<Location> WalkTo;

    void Start(){
        WalkTo = new List<Location>();
    }

    public void SetWalk(Vector2 end)
    {
        WalkTo = tools.FindPath(transform.localPosition, end);        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (WalkTo.Count > 0)
        {
            //run walking path
            WalkPath();
        }
    }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    void GoHome()
    {        
        SetWalk(cData.HouseLoc)
    }
}
```

The Child call to SetWalk sends a destination point to the ParentClass. Inside the function it uses FindPath to calculate a walking path from the objects start point to its destination. It returns list of points for a path to walk and puts them into WalkTo. The object should then traverse the path.

Comment: This isn't enough information to reproduce the issue. Also, `public void SetWalk(Vector2 end, Blocks)` is a syntax error.

Comment: Post complete scenario, what are `walkToLoc` and `blocks` you are passing as parameters to `SetWalk`  method and where are they coming from. also share the `tools.FindPath` method definition.

Comment: ChildClass inherits from ParentClass. If you instantiate ChildClass.. it has the functions and properties of ParentClass. You wouldn't try to access them on ParentClass or anything like that. You access them by looking at ChildClass. Where do you think you are sending the data to? and how are you reading it to see if it is staying changed or not?

Comment: I updated the question in hopes it will clear some of this up. I have my Update "listening" for the value WalkTo to have content and then run a function to move my object on the path that has been saved in WalkTo. When the SetWalk function completes it has loaded the new path into WalkTo. But once I reach the update, it no longer has that information.

Comment: and where does `tools` come from? **Note**: You do not "send" anything "to the ParentClass" ... your `ChildClass` **is** a `ParentClass` itself ... it inherits anything that your `ParentClass` can do so there should be no difference. However your code still is not complete ... how about posting your actual code? ;)

Comment: Without the WalkPath, Location, GoHome, SetWalk, cData and the FindPath code is impossible to help you. Right now I can only see that at the Start of your ParentClass you create a new List of Location(?) and in the Update of your ParentClass you call WalkPath every frame if your list is not empty. Also there is a GoHome method inside a ChildClass that call another method SetWalk that take cData.HouseLoc as parameter... Also ChildClass can do everything in the ParentClass + GoHome. Not even sure what you want to do here.

Comment: The only thing that I can imagine is that you expect WalkTo to be the same on the child and parent... while I think (based on your incomplete code) that you only update a copy (the one on your child or on your parent). Also WalkTo is a variable, you should really use lowercase for variables (so it should be walkTo camelCase is right).